# a Service, a Thread, an Activity and a static ArrayList

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a non-sticky service that's called on a regular basis via a broadcastreceiver to start a thread that'll perform some tasks. While the thread is running an ongoing notification shows some progress information, and a button to bring up a status page.

This status page shows a lists of items curerntly being processed, this list is a static ArrayList used by both the thread and this activity. When the status Activity is started I have a null check:

```
if(Global.statusItems == null)
{
    Global.statusItems = new ArrayList<StatusPageItem>();
}
```

The thread is still running, and has perfectly fine access to the ArrayList, but as soon as the Status Activity is brought up it'll recreate the ArrayList as if it were null.

So far I haven't been able solve the issue without saving the list using an ObjectOutputStream and reloading when the status page is started. Is there a more elegant solution I could use?

Regards,
Quint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your service is running on a different [process](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc)?

Comment: That was it, I experimented with keeping the service alive while it was running, so I put it in it's own process. Easy to overlook after a while!

Comment: +1 - well spotted! @Quipeace Note that you can still have concurrency issues if you don't synchronize your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the 2 lines of code (null test and creation of a new list) are atomic and that the allocation is visible from other threads.

The easiest way to do that is to synchronize that piece of code:

```
synchronized(Global.class) {
    if(Global.statusItems == null) {
        Global.statusItems = new ArrayList<StatusPageItem>();
    }
}
```

However, if you need to read the list from one thread and write to it from another thread, you will need to add extra synchronization when adding/removing/iterating to make sure that both treads see the same list - if you don't, it is possible that the writing thread adds an item to the list but the reading thread does not see it.

The easiest way would be to use a thread safe implementation of list:

```
synchronized(Global.class) {
    if(Global.statusItems == null) {
        Global.statusItems = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<StatusPageItem>();
    }
}
```

If memory / object creation is a concern (CopyOnWriteArrayList is not very efficient from that perspective), you can also use a synchronized collection instead:

```
synchronized(Global.class) {
    if(Global.statusItems == null) {
        Global.statusItems = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<StatusPageItem>());
    }
}
```

In that case, make sure you lock on the collection when iterating:

```
synchronized(Global.statusItems) {
    for (StatusPageItem item : Global.statusItems) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Even though your answer didn't directly resolve my issue, it helped me properly use the variables. Thanks :)